# Adding a style to HierarchicalDataTemplate generated MenuItems

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I'm adding my hierarchical data to a Menu-Control using the HierarchicalDataTemplate.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyType}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubItems}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

My Menu is created like this

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" Header="MainItem"></MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

How can a add a style to these generated MenuItems to set the `IsCheckable` property for example. It's important that the main MenuItem (header named "MainItem" here) don't applies this style so it's not checkable.

I've tried several approaches using `<Style>` and `<DataTemplate` but with no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
<Menu>
    <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
           ....
        </Style>
    </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
</Menu>
```

Or in you case:

```
<Menu>  
    <MenuItem Header="Text" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" ItemContainerStyle="{SomeStyle}"/>  
</Menu>
```

Comment: It applies to all MenuItems and not only to the subitems.

I would like to set a style to the MenuItems 'created' by the HierarchicalDataTemplate and not to all items in the menu.

Comment: It's working with a StaticResource to my style in the ItemContainerStyle like you said. Thanks